# Why this two backtracking algorithm have same outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I have made two implementations of a backtracking algorithm to solve this challenge on Codewars ( https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a6b24d4e626c59d5b000066 ) . My problem is that I grasp why the first implementation works but not why the second one . I think that my problem is in the return statement in the last line with the hash signs . I don't get why when the backtracking is terminating , since a solution was found, the second implementation returns the right solution instead of an empty list . Is it because when the solution is passed to the previous call of the function his value in the previous call ( which was with an element less ) is overwritten with the complete solution ?

First :

```
def square_sums_row(n):
    a , sol = [ x for x in range(1,n+1)] , []
    def recurse(a,sol):
        if a == [] : 
            return sol 
        for i,x in enumerate(a) :
            if is_valid(x,sol) :
                sol.append(x)
                iterate = recurse(a[:i]+a[i+1:],sol) ###########
                if iterate : ###########
                    return iterate #########
                sol.pop(-1)
        return False
    def is_valid(x,sol):
        if len(sol) == 0 :
            return True
        if (( sol[-1] + x )**0.5) % 1 == 0:
            return True
        return False
    return recurse(a,sol)
```

Second :

```
def square_sums_row(n):
    s , sol = [ x for x in range(1,n+1)] , []
    def recurse(s,sol):
        if s == [] :  
            return sol
        for i,x in enumerate(s) :
            if is_valid(x,sol) :
                sol.append(x)
                if recurse(s[:i]+s[i+1:],sol) : ###########
                    return sol ##############
                sol.pop(-1)
        return False
    def is_valid(x,sol):
        if len(sol) == 0 :
            return True
        if (( sol[-1] + x )**0.5) % 1 == 0:
            return True
        return False
    return recurse(s,sol)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the other answer, there is only one list object `sol` that is being passed around and returned. It's never copied. Here's another solution to emphasise that point. Here `sol` is not an argument anywhere, it's just taken from the closure, and only booleans are returned by the inner functions.

```py
def square_sums_row(n):
    sol = []

    def recurse(s):
        if s == []:
            return True
        for i, x in enumerate(s):
            if is_valid(x):
                sol.append(x)
                iterate = recurse(s[:i] + s[i + 1:])  ###########
                if iterate:  ###########
                    return True
                sol.pop(-1)
        return False

    def is_valid(x):
        if len(sol) == 0:
            return True
        if ((sol[-1] + x) ** 0.5) % 1 == 0:
            return True
        return False

    if recurse([x for x in range(1, n + 1)]):
        return sol
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Ahh ok I think that I understood...the object is unique , I thought that a new object was created at every iteration . To do so I have to copy the variable explicitly right? Thank you !

Comment: @Tortar exactly, or create a new list by other means, e.g. with slicing or `+` as you've done with `s`.

Answer (score 1):

It works because they return the same, both solutions return `sol`. It's just that the second one returns the variable `sol` directly, whereas the first one returns the output of the function (which is the same variable `sol` passed as argument).

Comment: Yes , but my problem is that the variable sol was already defined in the previous calls with a shorter list , why is it not going to pass for example with n = 15 which solution is [8, 1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2, 7, 9]  after first call  [8, 1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2, 7,9] then  [8, 1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2,7] ecc... until [ ] ?

Comment: In the first case I define a variable which is overwritten at every call with the *right* variable sol . In the second case I didn't do it .